# Multiprocessing in python - ensuring a minimum number of child processes are active

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I want to ensure that a mininum number of child processes spawned are still active at any given time; the currently spawns as below:

```
pool = Pool(processes=WORKERS)
pool.map(worker.run, range(WORKERS)) # pass process a number as its ID
```

There are certain cases where the workers would `return` or crash and burn because of an error - i would like to spawn a new worker in this case. is this at all possible?

Thanks,

Comment: Funny, looking at the multiprocessing sources, it seems Pool does this automagically, adding new workers as needed if any exits and the Pool is in the RUN state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple (dumb?) solution: periodically check all your workers, pop those that have returned and add new ones to the worker list (base code borrowed from [Doug Hellman](http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/multiprocessing/basics.html)):

```
import multiprocessing, random, time

def worker(num):
    """thread worker function"""
    time.sleep(random.randint(1,10))
    print 'Worker:', num
    return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    jobs = []
    for i in range(5):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, args=(i,))
        jobs.append(p)
        p.start()

    while True:
        time.sleep(2)
        for n, p in enumerate(jobs):
            if not p.is_alive():
                jobs.pop(n)
                i += 1
                p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, args=(i,))
                jobs.append(p)
                p.start()
```

Comment: Thanks - I think ill go for this for the moment. The internal re-processing doesnt seem to work for me though.

Comment: I did the same thing when we had to implement a custom process pool for database clusters.  Its effective enough, though I like using stdlib better, since I'm not on the hook for all that internal stuff.